# In TFS, how to Merge Up a branch to the Trunk which wasn't branched from directly?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tfvc

In TFS, I have noticed that you can only merge up your branch to a folder from which the branch was created apparently.

I have the following folders: Trunk, Tags and Branches.

When I have a release, I get the latest version of the trunk and branch it into the Tags folder, e.g. Project_01Aug2011. and when that release needs bug fixing, I'll create a branch from that tag, name it Project_01Aug2011_BugFixings and put it in the branches folder.

The problem is that now I've made some fixes in the branch and now those changes need to be merged up with the trunk itself but this doesn't seem to be possible.

TFS only allows merging up to a location where the branch had happened directly.

How could I merge my branch changes back into the trunk when using TFS? (in Subversion, it was quite simple and I could do so.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

First option is to merge from the changes from Branch to tags and then from tags to trunk. 
Second option is to merge the changes from Branch to trunk directly by performing a baseless merge using tf.exe commandline tool.

Comment: thanks for your 2 options. The first option can be done only if I create a new copy of the tag release; how could you copy a branch in TFS? the second option is unreliable as I'd need to see and check which areas and are not merged; can't auto-merge it blindly.

Comment: @The Light you should read this link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx, it has dialog to resole conflicts